# Configurable Product image swapping with swatch image?

Tags: magento2, product-images, swatches

I want to know that if, we select any swatch color for configurable product it will add feature image of product but it also show the default image in thumbnail gallery.

Like i have one product "kids cloth"

Here you can find image:
https://www.screencast.com/t/IfIWhmbD

Now i had selected pink swatch from option, it will change the feature image but also showing default image of product in thumbnail gallery.

Here you can find image:
https://www.screencast.com/t/DQSwTrR2QpT

Is there any option to hide this image.

TIA

Comment: Any solutions about that?

Comment: Yes it is been done by magento 2 variable options .